# Column behaving differently in content management Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013, content-manager

I have a weird problem in Tridion: I always open Tridion in Chrome. When I access my Folder structure in Tridion  I see 4 columns:

- Name
- Type
- From Publication
- Modified

However, since a few weeks, the 4th column *Modified* is not labeled and I can’t sort the Components based on the last modification date. Which is quite annoying!

Comment: Do you have any custom UI extensions enabled? If so, please turn them off and retest.

Answer (score 1):

Does it behave normally in Firefox?

Both Chrome and Firefox have automatic updated enabled by default and these updates have the tendency to break some of the CME's functionalities from time to time. The solution for this is to request the necessary hotfix from SDL support and apply it to your system.

Comment: We use virtual desktops with Chrome and I.E. installed.  No Firefox. We all have the same version of Chrome but this issue is not general, but particular for 1 user (we know of)

Comment: Could the user have zoomed in (using ctrl+scroll wheel)? I've seen Tridion UI acting odd when people zoom in. Might be worth checking this.